# How to plot time data on a D3.js line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time

I have a ton of data associated with time. I want to plot a, hopefully, simple line graph. A simplified example:

```
var data = [{ time: 13:30, size: 100 }, { time: 13:37, size: 500}, { time: 13: 42, size: 300 } 
{ time: 13:51, size: 150 }, { time: 13:56, size: 175 }, { time: 15:59, size: 75 }
{ time: 16:11, size: 75 }, { time: 16:37, size: 125 }, { time: 15:27, size: 200 } [...] 
{ time: 20:36, size: 500 }]
```

Many time values, and corresponding size values. Of course, I do not want to plot every single time value on this graph. Instead I want to take the lowest value, 13:30, then plot the time on the axes at 30 minute intervals (i.e. 13:30, 14:00, 14:30 ... 20:30) until I hit the latest time in my array of data. At the same time, I want to plot *every* size value. So, the graph will only display a tick for 13:30 and 14:00, but the values that correspond with 13.37, 13.42, 13.51, 13.56 will be plotted on the line.

How would I go about doing this?

My first attempt was something like this:

```
var graph = d3.select('.graph'),
    WIDTH = 790,
    HEIGHT = 250,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
       }

  xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
  yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top,   MARGINS.bottom]).domain([smallest, largest]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
```

NB the "smallest" and "largest" variables are the smallest and largest size values in my data array, calculated elsewhere. Obviously this is wrong because this would plot every single time value on the axes (as explained above, I do not want this) and even if I did it errors and glitches horribly.

How would I go about achieving what I want to achieve?

Thx
-- Gaweyne

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. d3.time.scale not d3.scale.linear()

```
xScale = d3.time.scale(range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain(new Date([//Earliest Date//]), new Date([//Latest Date//]))
```